# Dagger 2 / Inject Context In A Non-Activity Class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I would appreciate some help with the following problem; I have researched for quite some time, but unfortunately I have not been able to find something that can actually help me.

My goal is to inject the ***applicationContext*** into a class that is not an Activity, Fragment or BroadcastReceiver.

Following the codelab-tutorial by google, the code I have is the following.

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {

        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: SplashActivity)
    fun injectToRep(dependantClass: FirstRep)
}
```

Now I can inject the context to an activity, by calling the following in the onCreate() method of the corresponding activity. That works fine.

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
...
(application as App).appComponent.inject(this)
...
```

The problem I have is when I try to inject the context in a non-activity class, like my FirstRep class

**FirstRep.kt**

```
@SuppressLint("LogNotTimber")
class FirstRep{

    var context: Context? = null
        @Inject set

    fun logContext(mContext: Context? = context){
        Log.i("FirstRepo", "Context is: $mContext")
    }
}
```

Now when the function of the FirstRep class is called, the context is null. I guess this is expected. I know I am missing the step where the injection actually happens, but I can't figure out how to actually implement this. I've read that for non-activity/fragment classes I have to implement an interface, but I'm not sure if this is valid, since I haven't found any further posts that support this.

Using Dagger 2.26

Any help is very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using constructor injection for FirstRep. There is no magic behind @Inject, you need to do actual injection in that case.

Comment: Might be a dump question, but when the class is then called, am I not supposed to pass a context as a parameter? In that case I don't see how the di can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your FirstRep class should look similar to this:

```
class FirstRep @Inject constructor(val context: Context) {
    ....
}
```

When you need to use it, just inject it. It can be constructor injection or it can be field injection. For example, in your `SplashActivity` you could just do field injection:

```
@Inject
lateinit var firstRep: FirstRep
```

If you still want (for some reason) use field injection to make sure FirstRep has context, you need to inject it just like you do with `SplashActivity` ((application as App).appComponent.inject(this))